# How to run an android library project?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I want to make a Google Maps Android project, but when I use the google play service library in the project and i click `Run as` => `Android Application`. It gives the error "`Android Library project cannot be launched`". I tried many methods to solve this problem like: check or uncheck the "is Library" checkbox. But to no avail.

---

1. When I check the "is Library" checkbox it give the error "Android Library cannot be launched"
2. When I unchecked "is Library" checkbox it gives the error after some time "Unable to execute dex:GC Overhead Limit Exceed"

---

I fixed my problem.

Comment: You can't run a library. A library is just a codebase that has functions you can use.

Comment: what would you expect it to do?

Comment: I had problem in eclipse "add library project" but after some time I got solution of my problem so today I see my question then I post my answer for someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I change the value of `eclipse.ini` file like below :

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

It Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> How to run an android library project?

You do not run an Android library project. You use an Android library project to add functionality to an Android application project. You then run the Android application project.

> I want to make a Google Maps Android project

Follow [the instructions](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) to add the Play Services SDK to your Eclipse project.
Then follow [the instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) to use the Play Services SDK to create an application that uses the Maps V2 API.